# Remove Tabs layout's shadow in android. API >= 21

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I wanna remove this shadow from the TabLayout, but in api 21 nothing is working. I've tried defining windowContentOverlay to @null or elevation to 0dp or @null, but not seems to work.

Could someone help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh7ml.png
Heres is a screenschot.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@style/tabs"
 android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/tabs"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 android:id="@+id/viewpager"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am facing same problem and windowContentOverlay to @null also not worked for me. But when I changed android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout to LinearLayout it worked for me and bottom shadow of tablayout get removed.

I was tried with custom styles for android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout but did not get any success.

For now I keeping it in LinearLayout to remove bottom shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Set `app:elevation="0dp"` in your AppBarLayout (maybe in the TabLayout too..)

Comment: that is hiding the whole TabLayout